# setwaitedtimer function does not invoke a callback function in c

Tags: c, winapi, timer

hello i am trying a timer function in c program in windows.
my code is as below

```
#define  _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400
#define WT_EXECUTEINTIMERTHREAD 0x00000020
#include<stdio.h
#include<windows.h>

typedef void (*callbackfunction)();

void timerfunction(callbackfunction cb);

void callback()
{
SYSTEMTIME time;

int millis;

int seconds;
GetSystemTime(&time);
millis =time.wMilliseconds;
seconds=time.wSecond;
printf("\n\ninside callback second=%d, milli=%d\n\n",seconds,millis);
}

void timerfunction(callbackfunction cb)
{
 HWND hwndTimer=NULL;
 HANDLE hnd;
 PHANDLE h_buffer=(PHANDLE)malloc(sizeof(PHANDLE));

 int a;
 int qwDueTime;

  UINT_PTR nIDEvent=1;
  MSG msg;          // message structure 

  LARGE_INTEGER liDueTime;
 liDueTime.QuadPart=-100000000;
 a=10;
  nIDEvent=nIDEvent+1;
  hnd = CreateWaitableTimer(
     0,
    FALSE, 
    0);
  qwDueTime = -5*1000;
  liDueTime.LowPart  = (DWORD) ( qwDueTime & 0xFFFFFFFF );
  liDueTime.HighPart = (LONG)  ( qwDueTime >> 32 );

  SetWaitableTimer(hnd,&liDueTime,20,(PTIMERAPCROUTINE)cb,(LPVOID)a,TRUE);
  // WaitForSingleObject( hnd,20);

  // Wait for the timer.

  }




void main()
{
callbackfunction cb= callback;
int a;
a=10;
timerfunction(cb);

 Sleep(1000000);

}
```

the timer function does not call the callback function
please help.
i am working on windows

i have used the SetTimer() api but the time was more than i specified. I am doing this for an audio so i want the time accuracy in one milliseconds. it goes to the timer function but the callback function is not triggered. is the way i am using is correct or should i need to use the waitforSingleObject Api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are casting your function name to `PTIMERAPCROUTINE`. This may not be why your code does not work, but it is still very wrong.

Do **NOT** cast function names to anything. [If you need to cast a function, you're doing something wrong.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/05/06/10161590.aspx)

The signature for `PTIMERAPCROUTINE` is

```
VOID CALLBACK functionName(LPVOID lpArgToCompletionRoutine, DWORD dwTimerLowValue, DWORD dwTimerHighValue);
```

Your function **MUST** have this signature, **especially** the `CALLBACK`, as that has to do with the [calling convention](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx).

The same holds if/when you switch to a multimedia or performance timer. You will need to check those callback function signatures to get the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

why do you first set

```
liDueTime.QuadPart=-100000000;
```

which would fire the time 10 seconds after the call to SetWaitableTimer() and then

```
qwDueTime = -5*1000;
liDueTime.LowPart  = (DWORD) ( qwDueTime & 0xFFFFFFFF );
liDueTime.HighPart = (LONG)  ( qwDueTime >> 32 );
```

?
A negative due time of just 5000  100 ns units represents a relative delay of only **500 microseconds**!

Look at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) example:

```
#define _SECOND 10000000
qwDueTime = -5 * _SECOND;
```

You're missing a factor of 10000.

You should evaluate the return value of SetWaitableTimer to cover error conditions.
The linked MSDN sample code gives all details.

However, shorter delays in the range of 1 ms may only be achievable with [Multimedia Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743612%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: thank you for yr reply. can u pls give one example in c program to use Multimedia Timers

Comment: you may use search engines too. Anyway, [Using Timer Queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Using Multimedia Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757664%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) may be starters.

Comment: Windows 10 introduces CREATE_WAITABLE_TIMER_HIGH_RESOLUTION flags for CreateWaitableTimerEx, so this may be usable now.